# Can I post a message to facebook wall in my website?

Tags: html, facebook

I use the html code in [facebook developer](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/) but it can't post the message I put in the website
there just appear a windows that you can enter some words
but the 
'Facebook for Websites is super-cool' doesn't appear in the window
(just like the website did)

I have applied a appid, is there anything wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Facebook Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true
      });

      FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
          message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
    };

    (function(d){
       var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
       js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
       js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
       d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
     }(document));
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [this facebook platform update](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/), since July 12 the *message* field is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
var params = {};
params['message'] = 'Message';
params['name'] = 'Name';
params['description'] = 'Description';
params['link'] = 'http://apps.facebook.com/summer-mourning/';
params['picture'] = 'http://summer-mourning.zoocha.com/uploads/thumb.png';
params['caption'] = 'Caption';

FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', params, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Published to stream - you might want to delete it now!');
  }
});
```

Ref link: http://daipratt.co.uk/using-fb-api-to-make-a-full-post-to-a-users-wall/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
<p id='msg'></p>
<script>
FB.init( {
    appId : "YOUR_APP_ID",
    status : true,
    cookie : true
});

function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
        method : 'feed',
        link : 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
        picture : 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
        name : 'Facebook Dialogs',
        caption : 'Reference Documentation',
        description : 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
        document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: "
                + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
}
```

I suggest you to go through the documentation first...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the facebook comment plugin instead. It free and easy to implement.

if the user really like your page, they will write something good to you.

Do check out my website -> www.wootube.woolei.com